# Emulating 'source' command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to emulate bash's [source](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) command in powershell. The intent is to make any change to my `microsoft.powershell_profile.psl` and source it into the existing instance of powershell.

The following command works in command-line

```
$profile_content = [string]::join([environment]::newline,(get-content $profile))
invoke-expression $profile_content
```

All is good; I put the same into `microsoft.powershell_profile.psl` and it does not work.

```
function source{
        $profile_content = [string]::join([environment]::newline,(get-content $args[0]))
        invoke-expression $profile_content
}
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Can you share what values are being passed as `$profile` and `$args[0]`?

Comment: $profile is from the powershell environment. The value in my system is C:\Users\<name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. I invoke the source command as 'source $profile'

Comment: UPDATE: trying to re-invent the wheel in a wrong way. better use '.' as answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is already built into PowerShell:

```
. C:\path\to\some.ps1
```

See [`about_Operators`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

> **`.` Dot sourcing operator**
>   Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions,
>   aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current
>   scope.
>
> ```
> . c:\scripts.sample.ps1
> ```

Comment: This won't work for `.env` files

Answer (score 1):

Following should be enough:

```
function source { . $args }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` to look like this:

```
function source{
        $profile_content = [string]::join([environment]::newline,(get-content $args[0]))
        invoke-expression $profile_content
}

source $profile
```

Basically, you can't just define the function, you need to call it in the file as well. **HOWEVER**, the way your function is set up, it will result in an infinite loop. Replace your `function source()` with something else.

Comment: I don't quite get it. why would I want to include the call to the function as part of the function definition in 'Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'? I will call the function from command-line.And why the infinite loop? those two lines of code work in command-line.